# What is the difference between AWS and NFV

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, firewall, amazon-route53, nfv

What is the difference between the services AWS provides and Network functions virtualization(NFV)? are security groups, route53 and ELB considered NFVs?

Answer (score 0):

I believe AWS ELB, Route 53, etc., are considered NFVs, as these services are virtualized. What I mean is that when you create an ELB in AWS, nobody in their data center is physically installing a physical device for your ELB. Instead, a virtual ELB will just be created for your account.